# how to do read nested json file in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Hey i have a json file in my project, that json file is coming from the server side i need to read that json file in a client side

```
{
"color": {
    "white": "#FFFFFF",
    "black": "#262626",
    "neutral": {
        "20": "#222222",
        "90": "#EEEEEE"
    },
    "blue": {
        "50": "#0000ff",
        "90": "#3333ff"
    },
    "red": {
        "50": "#ff0000",
        "95": "#ff8080"
    },
    "Green": {
        "40": "#00cc00",
        "80": "#99ff99"
    },
    "Pink": {
        "30": "#ff0080",
        "80": "#ff99cc"
    },
    "Yellow": {
        "40": "#ffff00",
        "70": "#ffff66"
    },
    "border": {
        "brand": "#1589ee",
        "brand-dark": "#0070d2",
        "customer": "#ff9a3c",
        "destructive": "#c23934",
        "destructive-hover": "#a61a14"
    },
    "interactive-color": {
        "default": "#0000ff",
        "dark": "#3333ff"
    },
    "background-color": {
        "default": "#FFFFFF",
        "light": "#EEEEEE",
        "dark": "#222222",
        "disabled": "#EEEEEE"
    },
    "text-color": {
        "default": "#222222",
        "on-light": "#222222",
        "on-dark": "#FFFFFF",
        "light": "#222222",
        "disabled": "#222222",
        "link": {
            "default": "#0000ff",
            "on-dark": "#FFFFFF"
        }
    }
},
"font": {
    "family": {
        "text": "Salesforce Sans",
        "heading": "Arial"
    },
    "weight": {
        "light": "300",
        "regular": "300",
        "bold": "300"
    },
    "size": {
        "xx-small": ".625rem FONT_SIZE_1 10px",
        "x-small": ".75rem FONT_SIZE_2 12px",
        "small": ".8125rem FONT_SIZE_3 13px",
        "medium": ".1rem FONT_SIZE_5 16px",
        "large": "1.125rem FONT_SIZE_6 18px",
        "x-large": "1.25rem FONT_SIZE_7 20px"
    },
    "line-height": {
        "heading": "1.25",
        "text": "1.5",
        "reset": "1",
        "tab": "2.5rem 40px",
        "button": "1.875rem 30px",
        "button-small": "1.75rem 28px"
    }
},
"space": {
    "default": "16px",
    "xxs": "2px",
    "xs": "4px",
    "s": "8px",
    "m": "16px",
    "l": "32px",
    "xl": "64px",
    "inset": {
        "default": "16px 16px 16px 16px",
        "xxs": "2px 2px 2px 2px",
        "xs": "4px 4px 4px 4px",
        "s": "8px 8px 8px 8px",
        "m": "16px 16px 16px 16px",
        "l": "32px 32px 32px 32px",
        "xl": "64px 64px 64px 64px"
    }
},
"shadow": {
    "drag": "0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40)",
    "drop-down": "0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)",
    "header": "0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07)",
    "button-focus": "0 0 3px #0070D2",
    "inline-edit": "0 2px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16)"
},
"duration": {
    "instantly": "0s",
    "immediately": "0.05s",
    "quickly": "0.1s",
    "promptly": "0.2s",
    "slowly": "0.4s"
 }
}
```

and displayed in a format like

color-white
color-black
color-neutral-20
color-neutral-70
i am using angular js in a client side please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$http` service for fetching the `JSON` file from server.

```
$http.get('someFile.json').success(function(data) { 
   console.log(data.data)
   //data.data contains the response config    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the json file like this,

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
$http.get('data.json').
   then(function (response) {
       $scope.myData = response.data;
       console.log($scope.myData);
   });
});
```

and do a ng-repeat over the nested element using key value,

```
 <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in myData">
    <div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
     {{key}} {{key1}}
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/2x9PCOdCClyYlF5RdCmf?p=preview)**